# NSAttributedString not changing UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi I am trying to indent all but the first lines in a bullet point list. to do thins I am using an attributed string with a NSParagraphStyle. However it does not change the label at all. Any help?

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
style.HeadIndent = 50;

NSDictionary *styles=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:style forKey:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName] ;
NSAttributedString* attributedText= [[ NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:tipsString attributes:styles];
[coachingTips setAttributedText:attributedText];
```

Coaching tips is the UILabel.

Thanks,

Josh

Comment: What is coachingTips? what is tipsString?

Comment: Don't see any obvious issues with your code except for capital case property, might be the problem with your label setup - have you tried to change other attributes? E.g. Foreground colour to red - something easy to notice, try changing regular text not attributed to see if that affects label

Comment: Are you in mainthread? Since your code seems ok.

Answer (score -2):

You have to get the string value from the attributed string.
 try following..

```
NSDictionary *styles=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:style forKey:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName] ;
NSAttributedString* attributedText= [[ NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:tipsString attributes:styles];
[coachingTips setAttributedText:[attributedText string];
```